# gedit/ text editor document - how to show it in right click menu Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcuts, context-menu

when I right click on desktop I get the options like below.

[image]

[image]

I use to create many new gedit/ text editor documents during day work. It's very hard to save the file first and then move it to required location.

[image]

Is there a way to get new gedit/ text editor document option when I right click on desktop or in file manager?